# How to get both DKIM and domain verification code using V2 of Amazon SES API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-js

In order to complete SES domain verification I need 2 things:

- Verify the domain using [Amazon SES domain verification TXT records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-txt-records.html?icmpid=docs_ses_console)
- Setup easy DKIM for the domain [using CNAME DNS records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-dkim-easy-setup-domain.html)

Everything can be done via API as usual (I'm using SES API through a [CloudFormation custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)).

I'm trying to verify the domain AND create DKIM using [AWS.SESV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html) (2019).

The problem is that [AWS.SESV2.createEmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html#createEmailIdentity-property) creates both domain verification code and DKIM.

But I'm unable to get back the domain verification code from the API response...
I can find the 3 DKIM tokens in the API response but I cannot get the verification token although it has been created and it is visible in the AWS console.

I need to get the domain verification token from the API call because I'm doing IaaC. I don't want any manual copy/paste from the AWS console.

I can see the DKIM tokens in the doc bellow but where is the domain verification token that has been created?

[image]

---

Also I'm struggling understanding the difference between [AWS.SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html) (2010) and [AWS.SESV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html) (2019). Can everything be done using this 2 APIs? Which one for what use-case?

It look like domain verification can be done using [AWS.SES.verifyDomainIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#verifyDomainIdentity-property) but there is nothing similar in AWS.SESV2.

However DKIM can be done using both interface using [AWS.SES.verifyDomainDkim](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#verifyDomainDkim-property) and [AWS.SESV2. createEmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html#createEmailIdentity-property).

I'm trying to compose with both API

1. Using [AWS.SES.verifyDomainIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#verifyDomainIdentity-property)
2. And then [AWS.SESV2.createEmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html#createEmailIdentity-property)

But I'm facing an error when using [AWS.SESV2.createEmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SESV2.html#createEmailIdentity-property)

```
{
    "message": "Email identity foo.com already exist.",
    "code": "AlreadyExistsException",
    "time": "2020-08-31T08:26:15.600Z",
    "requestId": "7f87a9ac-b516-4403-a5dd-a19383e9f9ec",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 18.602196472
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert here but perhaps look at how these guys do it: https://github.com/binxio/cfn-ses-provider